# How can i recove data after delete query

Tags: mysql

I have run delete query in my table on my local system

```
   delete from table_name
```

Now i want to recover it. How can i do this Please help me. I am using php mysql. Please help me

Comment: Did u use "rollback" command???

Comment: I have run the query in phpmyadmin now i want to recover data.. Please help me. I have not run any other query still yet

Comment: sorry. Unless you use issue the command "start transaction" and "savepoint" before deleting the rows, you cant get the data back. If you have issued these commands earlier, then you can get the data back

Comment: Yes pavan Kumar... I got it You are right. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no. If you were running the server in default config, go get your backups (you have backups, right?) - generally, a `database doesn't keep previous versions of your data`, or a revision of changes: only the **current state**.

(Alternately, if you have deleted the data through a custom frontend, it is quite possible that the frontend doesn't actually issue a `DELETE:` many tables have a is_deleted field or similar, and this is simply toggled by the frontend.

Note that this is a `"soft delete"` implemented in the frontend app - the data is not actually deleted in such cases; if you actually issued a **DELETE, TRUNCATE or a similar SQL command**, this is not applicable.